# Symfony 3 - Doctrine - Difficulties on big query

Tags: php, symfony, count, doctrine

I'm annoyed because of a big query that goes a little in all directions.

She will use several tables:

- User
- Package
- User Type
- PackageDDLExternal (with foreign key User.id and Package.id to which I added a date attribute)

The purpose of this query is to be able to return a list that will contain:

The different existing packages with the number of times they were downloaded, for a certain period, with a given order (ASC or DESC) on the number of downloads, and all this depending on the user types whose ID table has passed as parameter.

So, I've :

**Paquet :**

[image]

**Type Utilisateur :**

[image]

**User:**

[image]

**The manyToMany relation between TypeUtilisateur and Paquet:**

[image]

**And the PackageDDLExternal:**

[image]

So I have already tried to create this query, but there seems to be synthax errors on the one hand (at the level of adding the order) and other things that seem to block...

```
public function getPackagesDDLBetween($debut, $fin,$typesUser,$ordre)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $queryBuilder = $qb
    ->select("pa.titre, count(p.package)")
    ->join("p.package","pa")
    ->join("p.user","u")
    ->where("p.date between :debut and :fin")
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in("u.typeUser", $typesUser[0]))
    ->groupBy("pa.titre")
    ->orderBy("count(p.package) :ordre")
    ->setParameter('debut',$debut)
    ->setParameter('fin',$fin)
    ->setParameter('ordre', $ordre);
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Using the $order, I get this error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 213: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'count'

But without it, my result is just null

Someone can help me please ?

EDIT: The query is almost good. The problem remains at:

```
->andWhere($qb->expr()->in("u.typeUser", $typesUser))
```

My $ tabUser is worth this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an alias:

```
->select("pa.titre, count(p.package) as total")
```

Order by alias:

```
->orderBy("total", $ordre)
```

Comment: It's better, but I've this : [Syntax Error] line 0, col 249: Error: Expected end of string, got ':ordre'.
My $ordre is "DESC" or "ASC", so why this problem ?

Comment: use ->orderBy("total", $ordre) instead of `->orderBy("total :order") (too speed for me Andrei Lupuleasa)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I haven't error now. However, my result is null :(

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on   `$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSql()` and `$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getParameters()` and debug

Comment: Okay, I made a var_dump, and I think that my ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in("u.typeUser", $typesUser))
isn't good. But in 4 hours, I did not manage to solve the problem

Comment: You should create another question with the query this `DQL` generates and the query you expect and link the questions.